# Is it possible to make a url dynamic value that's a selection list from the response of another call?

Tags: paw-app

Let's say I have a request that returns a list of objects. The JSON has an array of IDs. Another API endpoint allows me to get the details of an object, given that I provide an object id in the url. Is there any way to use the dynamic value of the list response in such a way where I can select, possibly from a dropdown list, one of the ids in my detail request?

As an example:

```
GET /api/customers

[
    {
        "id": "abc",
        ...
    },
    {
        "id": "foo",
        ...
    }
]
```

```
GET /api/customers/{Dynamic Response Value}

{Dynamic Response Value
    - "abc"
    - "foo"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible (yet) within Paw. So kinda hoping somebody proves me wrong now, or writes an extension for this.

However what I did for now is the following.

1) Open the management of the Environment, via the `Manage` button left above the requests, or use Menubar `Windows` -> `Environments`

[image]

2) Create a new Group and call it something like `id_from`

3) Add variables for every list request you like the feature for

4) Add the columns first_get with the Dynamic value: Response Parse Body
As key path it could be something like: `data.0.id`

[image]

5) Add the columns last_get, this one is more tricky, for this I used a combo of 2 Dynamic values: RegExp Match + Response Parse Body.

The Response Parse Body cannot give the last object. So I let it return every id.
Key path: `data.*.id`

Then use RegEx to filter out only the last one.
`"?([0-9A-Za-z\-]+)"?]$`

[image]

6) Now you can select the id_from you would like to use, and execute the request you need

[image]

For me this is just enough, because I mostly use filters and sorting to retrieve a list, and for the most part the first entry is enough for me.

Using the 2 I mentioned above you should be able to add also the second, third, fourth, etc listing.

**Warning** if the list doesn't contain an item you ask for, that environment variable will return empty. Depending on the API this could be harmful e.g. a DELETE on a /object/ vs DELETE /object/.